# How do i import math into kvlang?

Tags: math, import, kivy

how do I import math so that I can assign a labeltext to math.pi?????????

I am only going to provide .kv snippet

```
#: import math
… some code
Label:
    id: Label10
    text: str(sin(int(Label2.text) * math.pi/180)
```

The error:

raise ParserException(self, ln, 'Invalid import syntax')
 ParserException: Parser: File "*******************", line 2:
 ...
       1:#: kivy 1.10.1
       2:#: import math
       3:
       4::
 ...
 Invalid import syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `#:import imported_name imported_object`, so you could do `#:import math math` to import the `math` module with the name `math`.

This seems trivial in this case, but also extends to things like `#:import sin math.sin` with the same syntax.

Comment: ```import math math``` worked exactly as I needed it to thank you very much, assuming this would work as well with stuff like ```#:import randint random.randint```